# Using a variable to call a new instance of a class

Tags: java, chess

So, this may or may not be what you think, and i'm not entirely sure I've worded the question correctly, but here we go! I'm building a chess game and I'm trying to be dynamic with how I call my classes, build pieces, and set them on the board.

A run down on the code: I read a file which contains a piece such as "pla1", representing a piece, its color, its x coordinate, and its y coordinate. In this example, p = pawn, l = white, a = x coordinate on the board, 1 = y coordinate on the board. so:

*"the white pawn is on a1"*

Simple. Now Currently, I have a piece class that parses the piece from the file, and a specific class called "Pawn" so when I want to add a piece to the board, that piece has its own class that governs its moving ability and powers on the chess board and so on.

**The problem: I can't figure out how to dynamically set my piece class.** I could do this easily with a hardcoded version, as you'll see in the comments, or with an if statement. Is it possible to set my class with my string variable?

My code is below:

```
//reads from the file, puts each line into an arraylist
public void readFromFile(String fileName) throws IOException 
{
    String line;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

    //adds line to arraylist    
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
       fileLines.add(line.toLowerCase());

    //send each line in the list to method
    for(String item : fileLines) 
        buildPiecesFromFileAndGetLocation(item);
} 

ChessPiece[][] pieces = new ChessPiece[9][9]; my chessboard
String spawnPiece;
String spawnColor;
String pieceRepresentation;

String originx;
int originX;
int originY;


public void buildPiecesFromFileAndGetLocation(String item)
{
    //regex matcher // using this to match it: Pattern copyPiece = Pattern.compile("(?<piece>q|k|b|p|n|r+)(?<color>l|d)(?<x>\\w)(?<y>\\d)");
    Matcher copyMatcher = copyPiece.matcher(item);

    //hashmap for matching quicker; currently only has pieceMatches.put("p", "Pawn") within it      
    hashIdentities();

    if (copyMatcher.find())
    {

        spawnPiece = pieceMatches.get(copyMatcher.group("piece")); //spawnPiece becomes "Pawn"
        spawnColor = colorMatches.get(copyMatcher.group("color"));
        pieceRepresentation = spawnPiece + spawnColor;

        originx = copyMatcher.group("x"); //change letter to number 
        transferChars(); //changes letter "a" into integer "1"
        originY = Integer.parseInt(copyMatcher.group("y")); //string to int

        //PROBLEM:
        pieces[originX][originY] = new spawnPiece(pieceRepresentation); //since spawnPiece is now "Pawn" i want it to be able to call a new instance of the class Pawn. this way doesn't work. Solution?

        //logic:
        //pieces[a][b] = new (WHATEVER PIECE WAS MATCHED)("position + color");

        //hardcoded version:
        //pieces[1][1] = new Pawn("PawnWhite");

      }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is possible to do. Any help would be much appreciated, and if any elaboration of the code is needed I can provide.

Comment: You speak of "hardcoding" as though it is some kind of evil ... and of "dynamically doing this or that" as though it's some kind of best practice.  Java is a statically typed language.  If you're trying to engineer solutions that ignore that fact, then you're trying too hard and you're going to end up with bad code.  A chess game is replete with statically typed data (the pieces are all known at compile time).  I find your insistence that you must do this "dynamically" (so that you have no advantage of conpile time type checking and safety) to be absurd.

Comment: eh, its just something I find to be useful, and its an important part of OOP to be able to do it dynamically. I'd much rather do it in a dynamic way that shortens my code.

Comment: A different language would serve your needs better, then.  Reflective code in Java is slow.  It's also very verbose and ugly to look at and read.  Moreover, by the time you include all the exception handling, you have code that is almost always far longer and much more verbose.  When a statically typed solution exists, avoiding reflective code in Java gives you superior security, much greater type safety, superior robustness and maintainability, and greater performance.  The advantages of using a statically typed environment are compelling.

Comment: Just as to make this more concrete, if you had implemented your chess pieces as an `enum` class (and the player color as a strategy enum -- J. Bloch, Effective Java, 2nd Ed.) you could define *constant specific methods* to give you all the piece-specific behaviors you need ... all while maintaining the robustness and type safety of a statically typed solution.

Comment: I understand. In this case I did just want to find a more dynamic solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this article: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html

Quoting from it directly:

> There are two reflective methods for creating instances of classes:
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance() and Class.newInstance().
>   The former is preferred and is thus used in these examples because:
>
> 1. Class.newInstance() can only invoke the zero-argument constructor,
>      while Constructor.newInstance() may invoke any constructor, regardless
>      of the number of parameters.
> 2. Class.newInstance() throws any exception
>      thrown by the constructor, regardless of whether it is checked or
>      unchecked. Constructor.newInstance() always wraps the thrown exception
>      with an InvocationTargetException.
> 3. Class.newInstance() requires that
>      the constructor be visible; Constructor.newInstance() may invoke
>      private constructors under certain circumstances.

Let me add some code for you. First of all, you need to get a reference to the class whose instance you want to create. You already have the name of the class, so do this:

```
Class pieceKlass = Class.forName(spawnPiece)
```

Then get its constructor which accepts a single string and create an instance of the class:

```
Constructor ctor = pieceKlass.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class);
ctor.setAccessible(true);
ChessPiece piece = (ChessPiece)ctor.newInstance(pieceRepresentation);
```

Given that this piece of code is pretty complex and needs some error handling as well, you can now extract it out in a factory class neatly:

```
class ChessPieceFactory {
    public ChessPiece create(String pieceName, String pieceRepresentation) {
      ChessPiece piece;
      try {
        Class pieceKlass = Class.forName(pieceName)
        Constructor ctor = pieceKlass.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class);
        ctor.setAccessible(true);
        piece = (ChessPiece)ctor.newInstance(pieceRepresentation);
       // production code should handle these exceptions more gracefully
     } catch (ClassNotFoundException x) {
        x.printStackTrace();
     } catch (InstantiationException x) {
        x.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IllegalAccessException x) {
        x.printStackTrace();
     } catch (InvocationTargetException x) {
        x.printStackTrace();
     } catch (NoSuchMethodException x) {
        x.printStackTrace();
     }

     return piece;
  }
```

Since you have also tagged the question with the Chess tag, I should point out that you should use the standard [Forsyth-Edwards Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation) to populate the chess board. It uses upper case letters to denote white pieces and lower case letters to denote the black pieces.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Still messing with it but it works doing it this way.

Answer (score 2):

Use a factory class.

```
interface ChessPieceFactory {
  ChessPiece create(String pieceName);
}

class ChessPieceFactoryImpl {
  public ChessPiece create(String pieceName) {
    if("pawn".equals(pieceName))
      return new Pawn(pieceName);
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(pieceName);
  }
}
```

Comment: OP didn't want to use Ifs

Comment: He can use reflection (using `Constructor.newInstance()` if he wants), but a factory class is a good way to remove hardcoding from main code and separate file parsing and object creation.

Comment: Hardcoding is the evil only if it is disperse around the code; using newInstance() need to change file because he need full classname to instantiante object; if he wants to use "pawn" he need an external (hardcoded) file to map every piece name to right classname

Comment: ...which is equivalent to translating "p" to "pawn".